# C++ class constructor using a pointer to same class object

Tags: c++, constructor

Does it make sense to have class constuctor which takes a pointer to a object of the same class. The idea is to copy all the data for from the old object to a new object.

```
class Shape {
    ...
    public:
       Shape(string,string,...)
       Shape(Shape*)
}

Shape::Shape(Shape* ref) {
    layer = ref->layer;
    purpose = ref->purpose;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's just a pointer version of the copy constructor.  Normally it's done with a const reference.  See this article for more information:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

Answer (score 1):

No, this will only lead to confusing ambiguities and hard-to-catch errors (automatic conversion from pointer to object, anyone?). If initializing from a pointer make it explicit:

```
Shape s2 = *s1;
```

Comment: Thanks nightcraker, this make more sense.